# How to not use first observation as column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have some data files without column headings and every time I import them into the workspace R will read the first observation as variable names. Is there any way to prevent R from doing this?

Comment: What function are you using to import the data? Please show some code and example data.

Answer (score 1):

In `read.table` the option `header=FALSE` will not read the first observation as variable name.

Example:

```
write.csv(iris, "temp.csv")
read.table("temp.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)
```

Works for `read.csv(..., header=FALSE)` too.

Comment: Note that the default is `FALSE` for `read.table`, but `TRUE` for `read.csv`.

Comment: Haha~! Seems like that's the case. My bad.